# Postgres pg_dump effect on production DB

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump, mvcc

Is it possible to query how many multiversioned rows are there in a db ?

We want to measure the impact of **pg_dump** on a production database, and to suspend it in case of need: is it creating too many multiversioned rows?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`pg_dump` doesn't create any row versions (a.k.a *tuples*).

The only impact of `pg_dump` are the increased I/O load and the long running transaction it creates. The long transaction will keep autovacuum from reclaimimg dead tuples for the duration of the dump.

Normally that is no big problem unless you have very high write activity in the database. To mitigate that problem, you could create a streaming replication standby server, set `max_standby_streaming_delay` to more than the duration of `pg_dump` and let `pg_dump` run there.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Laurenz. Anyway,  these "dead' tuples are not really dead because they are visible to pg_dump, itself, but it may happen that updates on them produce "multi-versioned" rows maybe even migrating to different blocks and then causing reindexing, which is quite bad.  Maybe there is a way to detect when this is happening?

Comment: Oh, I understand. Dead tuples cannot be cleaned up during pg_dump, because it is running in a long read only transaction. You can measure the impact by comparing `n_dead_tup` in `pg_stat_all_tables` for all tables before and immediately after the dump.